# Cannot find module puppeteer-core/internal/puppeteer-core.js in node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\puppeteer.js when using browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, node-modules, browserify

I'm trying to change my script with browserify to use it in chrome extension, but it keeps giving this error and I couldn't solve it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/242zk.jpg)

this is my main code, all I want is for this code to work in the web extension environment, I tried using browserify for this, but it continues to give the problem in the picture.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const imdbScraper = require('easyimdbscraper')
const fs = require('fs');

// node popup.js

async function getMovieId (movieTitle) {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    userDataDir: "./tmp"
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${movieTitle}`);
  
  const Handles = await page.$('.yuRUbf');
  const anchorElement = await Handles.$('a');
  const title = await page.evaluate(el => el.href,anchorElement)
  
  const string = title;
  const regex = /tt(\d+)/;
  const match = string.match(regex);
  let imdbId = match ? match[1] : null;
  imdbId = "tt" + imdbId;

  await browser.close();
  
  return imdbId;
};



async function getInfoAboutMovie (movieId) {
  var info = await imdbScraper.getInfoByID(movieId)

  var infoJSON = JSON.stringify(info, null, 2); // JSON formatina dönüştürme ve düzgün bir şekilde formatlama
  
  fs.writeFile('movie_info.json', infoJSON, 'utf8', () => {
    console.log('Dosya başariyla yazildi: movie_info.json');
  });

 
}

async function changeData() {
  fs.readFile('./movie_info.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Dosya okunamadı:', err);
      return;
    }
    const info = JSON.parse(data);

    const imgElement = document.querySelector(".resim");
    imgElement.src = info.poster;
    console.log("hello there");
  });
}


async function main() {
  let movieTitle = 'spiderman across';
  movieTitle = movieTitle + " imdb";
  var movieId = await getMovieId(movieTitle);
  await getInfoAboutMovie(movieId);
  await changeData();
}

main();
```

Answer (score 3):

When I put puppeteer to the following version and tried it, the problem was solved for the moment:

```
npm i puppeteer@18.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while running e2e tests in nestjs using jest, and here is how i solved the problem ( in "puppeteer": "21.6.0")

- I went to `test/jest-e2e.json` and added a two module name mapper (

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "puppeteer-core/internal/puppeteer-core.js": "<rootDir>/../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/puppeteer-core.js",
  "puppeteer-core/internal/node/PuppeteerNode.js": "<rootDir>/../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/PuppeteerNode.js"
}
```